# string as array in python

Tags: python, arrays, query-string

I am  new learner in python.I need to make the following string as array.

```
['Soyuz_TMA-16', '2009-09-30']
['Soyuz_TMA-17', '2009-12-20']
['Soyuz_TMA-01M', '2010-10-07']
.......
.......
........
```

so that I can search in a text file for the string eg.['Soyuz_TMA-16', 2009-09-30'].If match together in some line eg:

```
    abcd 30th september 2009 skakk gkdka kkhhf Soyuz TMA 16.
    gfigka Soyuz TMA 16 hfkhf hghhg fghh 30th september 2009.
```

then it should return the whole line with marking the matches string.

Hopefully get a solution here.Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  You're going to have a tough time getting `'2009-09-30'` to match `30th september 2009` without some date parsing / coercion, and if there are other possible formats it's going to get messy and slow.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that if you show an attempt at a solution, others are both more able to understand your problem, and more willing to help you find the answer.

Comment: You probably should delete the _array_ tag - you presumably either meant _dict_, or else _sequence_, not _array_. (_array_ means an array of numeric types from NumPy. See the [documentation on standard types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html))

Answer (score 3):

Parse the list of missions and dates into a dict *missions*, whose keys are the string value of dates: *'2009-12-20'*.
Then, you can lookup the dict (*'if date in missions: ...'*).
You'll also need to be able to parse the text-form of dates (using regex) into *'2009-12-20'* form, I wrote a function 'dtuple_to_date()'.
(You could use a set rather than a dict, same idea. Looking up mapping types like dicts or sets is constant time i.e. O(1), rather than O(N) for a list of N elements.)

This code works:

```
import re

missions = """['Soyuz_TMA-16', '2009-09-30']
    ['Soyuz_TMA-17', '2009-12-20']
    ['Soyuz_TMA-01M', '2010-10-07']""".translate(None,',[]\'\"').split('\n')
missions = [t.split() for t in missions]

missions = dict((d,m) for m,d in missions)


input = """abcd 30th september 2009 skakk gkdka kkhhf Soyuz TMA 16.
gfigka Soyuz TMA 16 hfkhf hghhg fghh 30th september 2009.""".split('\n')


find_dates = re.compile(r'(\d+)\S*\s+(\S+)\s+(2008|2009|2010|2011)')

def dtuple_to_date(d,mth,y):
   """convert ('30','september','2009') to '2009-09-30"""
   m = {'january':1,'february':2,'march':3,'april':4,'may':5,'june':6,
        'july':7,'august':8,'september':9,'october':10,'november':11,
        'december':12}[mth.lower()]
   return "%s-%02d-%s" % (y,m,d)


for idx,line in enumerate(input):
    for (day,mth,yr) in find_dates.findall(line):
        date = dtuple_to_date(day,mth,yr)
        #print 'Looking up', date
        if date in missions:
            print 'Line %d: reference to mission %s on date %s' \
                % (idx, missions[date], date)
```